# Is it possible to make an object null or undefined through a pointer?

Tags: javascript, pointers

```
let person = {name: "Annah", age: 18};
let pointer = person;
pointer = undefined;
```

person doesn't become undefined, only pointer?

Comment: `person` itself is also *pointer*. Can you tell what language you come from? And why you think set a *pointer* would modify the object?

Comment: In C++, you can declare `pointer` to be a reference to the variable `person`. There is no equivalent in JavaScript.

Comment: @appleapple I started in javascript and I also know some java. It helps me to have a pointer because I have an array with many objects.

Comment: I don't write java, but you still cannot do this in java IIRC.

Comment: And set a *pointer* to null is not more special than set it to another object, which should not overwrite the origin one IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You could emulate that beahviour using a wrapping object:

```js
const reference = value => ({ 
  value,
  free() { this.value = undefined },
});

const val = ref => ref.value;

let person = reference({name: "Annah", age: 18});
let pointer = person;

console.log(val(person));

pointer.free();

console.log(val(person));
```

Through that you cannot access `person.name` anymore, you have to dereference it using `val(person).name`.

---

In theory you could create two variables referencing the same thing:

```js
with({ 
 person: undefined,
 get pointer() { return this.person; },
 set pointer(value) { this.person = value },
}) {
  person = { some: "test" };
  console.log(pointer);
  pointer = undefined;
  console.log(person);
}
```

But please, don't do that (except for fun).

Comment: your code is wrong, `SyntaxError: missing = in const declaration`

Comment: please use snippet , your code retur 2 NaN, this whitch is not undefined

Comment: @mrj please try again ... :)

Comment: @mrj what are you talking about?

Comment: to get origin name (person) by `Object(pointer) ` possibles values

Answer (score 0):

Make an object to contain your records and access them through their identifiers. For example, using `name` as the identifier:

```
const people = {};
const person = { name: "Annah", age: 18 };

people[person.name] = person;

console.info(people[person.name]);  // Annah is there

delete people[person.name];

console.info(people[person.name]);  // undefined - Annah is gone
```

Comment: Yeah I guess it will work, but it's a bit of a hacky way. Let's just say javascript sucks...

Comment: It's actually not hacky. It's just the way you would do it in Javascript and just a matter of getting used to the language. We tend to complain about languages we're not used to. One could argue that pointers are messy and that C++ is verbose and sucks just the same. In the end I guess it's just like religion: each person has their own beliefs and we have to struggle to accept that there are other points of view that are equally valid. All popular languages have their good and bad parts - we just have to get to know them better and remember to not complain too much :-)

Comment: ... to add to the great comment above: Languages have a purpose. C++ uses pointers because it is designed tp be very performant, and managing memory manually is fast (but also complicated). JS was invented to make webpages blink, that doesn't have to be fast, just fast enough and using references and garabge collection the language is easy to handle for newbies (and professionals that want to do more with less code :))

Answer (score 0):

There are no pointers in javascript as of ES6, but there is a workaround for this...

The Pointer Class:

```js
/****
USAGE: 
var a = 3;
var b = new Pointer("a")
b.value = 1
console.log(a) // Logs "1"
****/






class Pointer{
  constructor(str){ // Called when "new Pointer()"
    this.var = str // Assign Pointer.var to the string
    this._value = window[str]
  }
  
  set value(value){
    window[this.var] = value
    this._value = value
  }
  
  get value(){
    return window[this.var]
  }
  changeLocation(str){
    this.constructor(str)
  }
  delete(){
    delete window[this.var]
  }
  
}
```

The Example

```js
// Put the Pointer Class HERE
var person = {name: "Annah", age: 18}; // Notice that let => var as Pointer cannot access lets and consts
var pointer = new Pointer("person"); // Pointer to person
pointer.value = undefined; // Sets value to undefined
// OR:
pointer.delete() // Deletes it permanently
```